# Replacing non-identical numbers in batches of files with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace a combination of letters and numbers in multiple files using the sed command but I cannot find the right way so far. All the lines in a single file have the same number following the letter `M`, but the number varies across files. For instance, in file `M800.txt`, I am trying to replace this:

```
M800_Arch_nautilus_Posei XXXCV  
M800_Arch_exocet_Pleiade DZEFE
```

by this:

```
Arch_nautilus_Posei XXXCV  
Arch_exocet_Pleiade DZEFE
```

And in file `M56.txt`:

```
M56_Arch_nautilus_Posei FGYYE  
M56_Arch_exocet_Pleiade UJEYY
```

by:

```
Arch_nautilus_Posei FGYYE  
Arch_exocet_Pleiade UJEYY
```

I am basically trying to remove `M*_` in each file in a directory that has 800 files with such characters at each line of each file.

I am really new to this and so far tried this without success:

```
sed -i 's/\M._$*//g' *.txt
```

Maybe someone can point the error here?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `sed`?

Comment: Not really but I was trying to understand how to use it at the same time. Obviously any trick would do to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assuming the input was `>M800_Arch_nautilus_Posei XXXCV`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622508/replacing-non-identical-numbers-in-batches-of-files-with-sed/53628575#comment94106931_53623075) and such, then:

```
sed -i 's/[[:alnum:]]*_//' *.txt
```

...would replace that line with:

```
>Arch_nautilus_Posei XXXCV
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 2):

> All the lines in a single file have the same number following the letter M, but the number varies across files.

Then all you need to do is deleting everything until first underscore plus the underscore itself.

```
sed -i 's/^[^_]*_//' *.txt
```

- `^` matches the beginning of a line,
- `[^_]*` matches zero or more non-underscore characters,
- `_` matches an underscore.

Comment: Thank you this is great. One additional question, if each line instead of directly starting by M800 starts by >M800 what would be the corresponding code?

Comment: Sorry my comment was confusing, I meant that I would actually like to keep the ">" at the beginning of the line and only remove the "M*_"

Comment: Then you use `sed 's/^[^_]*_/>/' *.txt`

Comment: or `s/M[^_]*_//`